# Not any vs not at all

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

For both questions and statements I'm unsure about the use of "not at all" or "not any".
Please consider the following example (statements)

> That perfume doesn't smell good at all.

Would the following sentence also be correct?

> That perfume doesn't smell any good.

Please also consider the next example (questions)

> Is the food any good?

Would the following sentence also be correct?

> Is the food good at all?

Comment: *X isn't any good* (more idiomatically in most contexts, *X is **no** good*) usually means the same as *X is **no use, unsuitable*** (for some ***contextually-relevant purpose***). But *X is **no good*** doesn't usually carry that "purpose" connotation - it often just means X is "defective" in some way (regardless of whether this has anything to do with being "useful").

Comment: ...So in the cited context, the idiomatically "unusual" ***doesn't smell any good*** version might be understood as implying that the smell of that particular perfume will not be *suitable* for the current purpose. Perhaps it's a perfectly good perfume to give to a young woman - but the speakers are out shopping for perfume to give to their grandmother, and they know perfectly well she wouldn't use that particular fragrance because it's not "age appropriate".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Okay thanks. But what about other adjectives (other than "good")? Can I ask: "Is your car any fast?", Or say "My car is no fast/not any fast."?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that (I mean, "Why?"; your other suggestions *aren't* valid). But it does lead me to think: *Is it **any wonder** non-native Anglophones find English difficult?* More emphatically, ***It's no wonder** you're confused!*

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here - let's start with "not at all" vs "not any" in general contexts.

- The determiner "**any**" is used to refer to **one or some of a thing or number of things**. So, this is appropriate with "countable" things.
- "...**at all**" is used for **emphasis**, to show the **extent or degree** of something.

For example:

> "*There aren't any people here*" - this is correct, because you can *count* people.
>   "*I am not at all hungry*" - this is correct, because you can have *gradations* of hunger.

---

However, "any good" is an *idiomatic* expression. It doesn't really follow the rules above. You can ask if something *is* "any good" as a way of enquiring if something is good, or not, or to what extent someone feels it is good/useful.

In response, people will say that something is "quite good" or "very good" to show the degree to which they feel it is good or useful. The expression "*it isn't any good*" means that, in their opinion, it has *no value at all*.

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean that the "any good" question (e.g. Is the food any good there?) is an exception? Is it the only exception, or in other words: is "good" the only non-countable adjective that can be used with "any"?

Comment: Noting things like *Is this [of] **any good / benefit / use / value / worth** [to you]?*, I'd say all the highlighted terms are nouns, not adjectives.